# Changing coordinates in a grid

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm a developer very bad in math, and I got a problem that I'm not able to solve.

I got a grid each cell got a position X and Y like shown in the picture below

[image: diagram]

Actually I got the red coordinates, I need the green ones...
My cells are in diagonal so it takes the diagonal line as center.

If I do `X - Y` it would be good for the first col, but the second one will have 1 too much.

I don't have many clues

Sorry if I put the wrong tags but I don't have many ideas of where to put it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the red coordinates $X$ and $Y$, and the green coordinates $X'$ and $Y'$.  Then

$$X' = (Y+X)/2,$$

$$Y' = (Y-X)/2.$$

You can think of this as the result of applying a rotation of $45^\circ$ clockwise to the vector $(X,Y)$, then normalizing the result.

Comment: Wow thank you !
Sorry for my late reply but I needed to go somewhere.
Thank you very much

Comment: You're very welcome, @Shadowbob.

Comment: And now to have the opposite ?

Comment: Oh I found it `X' - Y' = X` and `X' + Y' = Y`